# Is there a way to make a VPN apply every time iPhone reboots? It's annoying having to re-enable

Tags: iphone, network, vpn

I use the OpenVPN app to encrypt my network connections on my iPhone as well as a VPN service, but every time my phone reboots I have to remember to re-enable my VPN.

Is there a way to have this occur automatically?